# React Log out all Pages using Context and Axios interceptors

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I am outside a React component but need to update my auth context 'AuthContext' to delete the existing user to log the user out entirely from all logged in pages

I'm able to dispatch a redux action using Redux. How can I achieve the same using Context?

Below are my code... the logOutAll function is not working because useContext can't be used outside of a React component or function

Appreciate advise from those who have successfully implemented this. Thanks

```
import { useContext } from "react"
import axios from "axios"

import { AuthContext } from "../context/authContext"

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:5000/api",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
})

/**
 intercept any error responses from the api
 and check if the token is no longer valid.
 ie. Token has expired or user is no longer
 authenticated.
 logout the user if the token has expired
**/

// const logOutAll = () => {
//   const { authStatus, setAuthStatus } = useContext(AuthContext)
//   console.log(authStatus)
//   setAuthStatus({
//     ...authStatus,
//     isAuthenticated: false,
//     isLoading: false,
//     user: null,
//   })
// }

api.interceptors.response.use(
  res => res,
  err => {
    if (err.response.status === 401) {
      console.log("log out all")
      logOutAll() //! CANNOT WORK BECAUSE UseContext cannot be called outside React function 
      or component

    }
    return Promise.reject(err)
  }
)

export default api
```

Comment: Where are you getting stuck? Are you struggling with the concept of a provider, or something else? If you're using hooks then you can define all your API requests inside the hook itself, or the context provider if using context. For this I would imagine you'd create an AuthProvider that wraps your app and defines all the related API related handlers, and passes the user down to the rest of the app, along with any of the handlers you want the app to be able to access. If this structure is what you need I can provide a basic example.

Comment: @James, thanks. my axios interceptors were placed inside an api.js file which is neither a React component thus i can't access nor update my auth context from there. I have moved in to my app.js file instead which is a React component and so far, it seems to work ok. I have put the codes in answer below. If you have suggestions to improve the code, appreciate any advise. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I set up my axios interceptors in my app.js file instead and it seems to be working fine

```
const App = () => {
  const { authStatus, setAuthStatus } = useContext(AuthContext)

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkLoggedIn = async () => {
      let token = localStorage.getItem("@token")
      if (token === null) {
        localStorage.setItem("@token", "")
        token = ""
      }
      const res = await api.get("/users/me", {
        headers: {
          authorization: token,
        },
      })

      //TODO
      // const token = localStorage.getItem("@token")
      // console.log("TOKEN", token)
      // if (token) {
      //   setAuthToken(token)
      // }
      // const res = await api.get("http://localhost:5000/api/users/me")

      console.log(res)

      setAuthStatus(authStatus => ({
        ...authStatus,
        isAuthenticated: true,
        isLoading: false,
        user: res.data,
      }))
    }
    checkLoggedIn()
  }, [setAuthStatus])

  api.interceptors.response.use(
    res => res,
    err => {
      if (err.response.status === 401) {
        setAuthStatus({
          ...authStatus,
          isAuthenticated: false,
          isLoading: false,
          user: null,
        })
      }
      return Promise.reject(err)
    }
  )
```

Comment: Just make sure this behaves how you expect. At the moment that useEffect will run every time `setAuthStatus` changes, which it will do on EVERY render of `App` unless you've wrapped setAuthStatus in a `useCallback` inside your AuthContext

Comment: it seems to be working fine so far. I want to check the auth status on every render of app to make sure the user is authenticated. if the user is not authenticated, i ll need to update the context to set the user to unauthenticated

Comment: if there is a better place to place the axios interceptors, will welcome any feedback. Thanks :)

Comment: Making an API request on every render is almost certainly not what you want. It'll be heavy on your server and doesn't add any value. You likely only need to check if the user is logged in when you make an API request (i.e. to get new data or post something). If you really want to make regular checks just to see if they're still authenticated then it would be better to use a `setInterval` and poll your server once every x seconds/minutes, so at least you're in control of that frequency. Renders are just about how your UI updates and should have nothing to do with authentication.

Comment: good point @james.  my approach was based on those online course. eg https://github.com/myhendry/devconnector_2.0/blob/master/client/src/App.js . this code is from an online course and they checked at every app render

Comment: i see your point though. good input. let me think through how to improve on the design :)